# NginX Log Rotation

Tags: logging, nginx, logrotate

I am serving a couple different domains through NginX on the same server and they each log to their own file.  I need to set up a script to rotate, and compress these files and add it to cron.

I know I have to do something to get NginX to open a new log file once I move the old one.  Can someone give me the procedure for safely rotating nginx log files?  I'm guessing I need to use logrotate, how do I configure it?

System:

- Ubuntu 9.04 server ed.
- nginx/0.7.61

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It has become a sort-of informal semi-standard among Unix daemons that they flush and/or rotate their log files, when you send them a hangup signal (`SIGHUP`). Nginx doesn't follow this convention to the letter, but it responds to the `USR1` signal the same way, as is documented on the Nginx website under the title [Log Rotation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/logrotation).

So, you could try something like

```
kill -s USR1 `pidof nginx`
```

Comment: another way, "pkill -USR1 -n -x nginx"

Answer (score 11):

logrotating nginx logs:

```
# nginx SIGUSR1: Re-opens the log files.
/opt/nginx/logs/access.log {
  missingok
  notifempty
  delaycompress
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    test ! -f /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid || kill -USR1 `cat /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
 endscript 
}

/opt/nginx/logs/error.log {
  missingok
  notifempty
  delaycompress
  sharedscripts
  postrotate  
    test ! -f /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid || kill -USR1 `cat /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
  endscript
}
```

logrotating rails production log:

```
/home/app_user/apps/railsapp/log/production.log {
  missingok
  notifempty
  delaycompress
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    test ! -f /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid || kill -USR1 `cat /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
  endscript
}
```

Comment: In which file should I put this?

Comment: if using ubuntu, you should put these lines of code into this file : `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` . and it will take effect.

Answer (score 4):

If you use logrotate, add the following (with correct location) into nginx's section of logrotate.conf:

```
postrotate
  kill -s USR1 `cat /location/of/nginx.pid`
endscript
```

According to [logrotate(8) man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)